# Display Custom Order Filter In WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, admin, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to display a custom admin order column in WooCommerce and I am having a hard time getting the code right here.

I have this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'display_order_data_in_admin', 10, 1);
function display_order_data_in_admin( $output )
global $wp_query
$output .= wc_product_dropdown_categories( array(
'show_option_none' => 'Filter by Location',
'taxonomy => 'product_tag',
'name' => 'product_tag',
'selectd' => isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product_tag'] ) ? $wp_query->vars['procut_tag'] :
) );
return $output;
}
```

I am having a hard time displaying a column for filtering my orders by location that has been selected in checkout.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wc_add_new_order_admin_list_column' );

function wc_add_new_order_admin_list_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['billing_country'] = 'Country';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wc_add_new_order_admin_list_column_content' );

function wc_add_new_order_admin_list_column_content( $column ) {

    global $post;

    if ( 'billing_country' === $column ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        echo $order->get_billing_country();

    }
}
```